# Define custom layout & class to each joomla menu levels

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, menu

I want to add custom layout and class to joomla menu levels.

This is the default.php codes of my menu

```
<nav class="uk-navbar <?php echo $class_sfx; ?>" id="ad-menubar">
<ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
<?php foreach ($list as $i => &$item){
    $class = 'ad-menu-item item-' . $item->id;
    $attribute = '';

    if ($item->id == $default_id)
    {
        $class .= ' default';
    }


    if (($item->id == $active_id) || ($item->type == 'alias' && $item->params->get('aliasoptions') == $active_id))
    {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' uk-active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type == 'alias')
    {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
        {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
        {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->type == 'separator')
    {
        $class .= ' divider';
    }

    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }

    if ($item->parent)
    {
        $class .= ' uk-parent';
        $attribute = "data-uk-dropdown=\"{justify:'#ad-menubar', mode:'click'}\"";
    }

    echo '<li class="' . $class . '" '. $attribute .'>';

    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'component':
        case 'heading':
        case 'url':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        echo '<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar"><ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-navbar">';
    }
    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower)
    {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></div></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

its deeper levels generated with this code

```
if ($item->deeper)
    {
        echo '<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar"><ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-navbar">';
    }
    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower)
    {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></div></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
```

I want to add custom divs and classes to each levels of dropdown for example I want to make third level menu multi column how could I define each level divs please help me I need it now its very important ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit each menu item in Menu Manager and enter a Page Class under the Page Display Tab.

You will then have unique selector classes in CSS to apply whatever styling you wish.

Comment: no no i dont want this i want to make dropdown menu items multi coloumn but not with css flex with divs please help me about this